# No Email Send for Password Reminder After Reset Password in Magento1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento1.9.2.4, email-reminders

My All emails are being sent except one, which is a reminder mail after reset Password.

Suggest what can I do achieve this.

Comment: Question is not bit clear on which mail that you are talking about here!!! Are  you talking about reset password email which sent out to customer when they try to reset their password  or the reminder mail to reset customer password ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento didn't send email forgot password change confirmation. You can write custom code for that. Write one observer and use below code. 
You can use event " **customer_save_before**"

```
public function checkPasswordChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $event              = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer           = $event->getCustomer();
    $postData           = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

    if($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer && !$customer->isObjectNew()) {

        if( $postData['change_password'] == 1 && $postData['current_password'] != $postData['password'] ) {
          //write email code here. 
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```